Find the General maximal solution of the following homogeneous solution
Find the General maximal solution of the following homogeneous solution

$2xy+(x^2-y^2)y'=0$

My attempt:-
Using the Homogeneous differential equation solving method( Puttin $y/x=p$), we get
$x(y)=\pm \sqrt{\frac{C}{y}+\frac{y^2}{3}}$
Case 1 $C> 0$
there can be two ways, If $y>0$, then $ x(y)$ is well defined. Suppose $y<0$, then $\frac{C}{y}+\frac{y^2}{3}\ge 0$
Multiplying $y$ on both sides of inequality,
$C\leq -\frac{y^3}{3}\implies -3C\ge y^3.  $ Since $y=x^{1/3}$ is increasing. We can write $(-3C)^{1/3}\ge y.$  So, two intervals where $x(y)$ is well defined $y\in (0,\infty) \cup (-\infty, (-3C)^{1/3}).$
Case 2 $C= 0$
$x(y)$ is well defined for all $y \in \mathbb R$
Case 2 $C<0$
We can treat like case 1.
Could you check the case 1. Is my approach correct?
Thank you in advance
